# Canny edge detection not working on Gaussian blurred images

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-preprocessing, opencv

I am trying to detect edges on this lane image. First blurred the image using Gaussian filter and applied Canny edge detection but it gives only blank image without detecting edges.

[image: Input image]
[image: output image after canny detection]

I have done like this:

```
#imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image= mpimg.imread("Screenshot from Lane Detection Test Video 01.mp4.png")
image = image[:,:,:3]
image_g = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_g, (3, 3), 0) 
threshold_low = 50
threshold_high = 100
image_blurred = image_blurred.astype(np.uint8)
image_canny = cv2.Canny(image_blurred, threshold_low, threshold_high)
plt.imshow(image_canny,cmap='gray')
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to blur your image before passing it to `Canny`.

OpenCv's implementation already includes a blurring step. So by passing a blurred image, you're effectively blurring the image twice.  That will suppresses edges.

Read about openCv's implementation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html).